# Can I use a diode to lower the voltage for a 12 V LED strip?

Tags: voltage, diodes, led-strip

I have a 12 V LED strip that I want to use in abmn automobile - so about 14 V. Can I put in a diode or two to lower the voltage by a few volts (by using the diode's forward voltage)?

Is it a safe solution, to make sure the LED strip does not get too much voltage?

Also, I think it would be as efficient as using a DC/DC converter (with ~85% efficiency).

Comment: Why worry about efficiency? the car's alternator won't even notice one LED...

Comment: It is for usage when alternator is not working - car is stationary.

Comment: If the alternator is not working then you won't get 14V.

Comment: You may be better off with just a 2.2 Ω power resistor.

Comment: Please link the data sheet for the LED strip.

Comment: I have decided to use 1 ohm resistor in series. Calculations in LTspice said it would be around 88% efficiency, so as good as a DC/DC converter. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you size the diodes for the required power dissipation, it will be safe.

However, the voltage over a 12V lead-acid battery system, such as in a car, will vary between 11V and around 16V depending on the charge level, whether it is being charged, and float vs boost vs equalize charge regime.

If the LED string is sensitive enough that you are worried about the 2V drop, I'd suggest you use a small DC-DC converter to give you truly stable 12V across the full voltage range.

They are fairly cheap, and often described as "12V stabilizers" as they are used for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, it will work. You need to consider the sizing of the diodes because those strips can use a fair amount of current. The ones I have are over 2 amps. The diodes will probably get hot depending on the current. Use 0.7 volts for each diode in series then multiply that by the current, that will give you the wattage you are losing. You can compare that to the efficiency of the converter. Personally I would use SEPIC converter so the lights do not flicker and I can set the voltage to where I want it.

Comment: LEDs will be 19.2W. I am thinking about using diode with ~1.3V voltage drop at this current. So it would disipate about ~2W of heat?

Comment: You are correct, not you need to look up what it can dissipate and what you need to keep the temperature in range, preferably below 70C which is very hot to the touch.

Comment: This is what I am afraid of. Would simple diode not overheat in closed box for few hours of use?

Comment: @Ridi Depends which diode it is, and whether you live in Antarctica or Sahara. Such a diode might have temperature increase of 50 celcius per watt. If ambient is 25, two watts makes temperature to rise to 125 degrees. Awfully hot and awfully close to typical maximum of 150 degrees.